# Using ArcGIS for Desktop with TauDem?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, taudem

I am trying to do a hydrological analysis in ArcGIS 10.3 using Taudem toolbox. I've installed the tool following the instructions that can be found here (http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/downloads2.html). When I start the process with the pit removal, the tool gives me this error:

[image]

The Dem is in tiff format (I tried also with a .asc file), but the error continues.

Comment: Please provide all error messages as text rather than pictures so that they are available for future searches.

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicate a python dependency issue, specifically it can not find the numpy module.

I would guess this is one of the following:

1. a python-path issue. Do you have multiple python installations eg 3 and 2?
2. did you not have admin rights when installing TauDEM perhaps?
3. Is Gdal installed

Test if the command line tools work if yes it's a python issue, if no its probably gdal

Comment: thanks for the reply. I've checked the command line. It works well, so maybe is a python issue. How could I solve it?

Comment: This is tricky, i would try uninstalling and reinstalling, and check that the python paths are set correctly. Also, make sure you install as admin. You could just use the command line tools, these should be faster than the arcgis version, although not as interactive.